# CasperJS click not firing click event

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am having trouble with CasperJS.  I load the page for our site, then try to click on the signup button.  It's supposed to open a modal, but nothing happens.  It works in actual browsers, and very similar functionality works in other tests on other pages.

What could I be doing wrong?  What else would help you, the wider internet, help me?

casperjs --version: 1.1.0-beta3
phantomjs --version: 1.9.7

Casper test snippet:

```
casper.then(function() {
    casper.open(DOMAIN);

});

// wait added for debugging. 
casper.then(function() {
        casper.wait(2500);
});

// many different ways of trying to click and debug:
casper.then(function() {
    casper.click('[data-js="company-search-view-jobs-button-reg"]');
    var x = casper.evaluate(function() {
        var f = $("[data-js='company-search-view-jobs-button-reg']");
        f.click();
        var q = document.getElementById("foo");
        q.click();
        $('#foo').click();
        return $("[data-js='company-search-view-jobs-button-reg']")[0].innerHTML;

    });

// this prints the expected text, so it is definitely on the right page.
    casper.echo(x);
});

//waiting in case it was slow for some reason
casper.then(function() {
    casper.wait(2500);
});

// takes a screenshot. uses casper.capture under the hood.
casper.then(function() {
    util.screenshot("fff", SCREENSHOT_OPTIONS);

});
```

From the JS with the click handler:

```
var $companySearchViewJobsBtnNeedReg = $("[data-js=company-search-view-jobs-button-reg]");
[...] 
$companySearchViewJobsBtnNeedReg.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
[library code for opening the modal]
```

The HTML on the page:

```
<div class="columns xlarge-8">
    <div class="company-basic-info__logo left">
        <img class="company-basic-info__logo-img" src="/images/logo_placeholder.png" alt="[Standard Values] logo">
    </div>
    <div class="header-container">
        <h1>Standard Values</h1>

        <button class="company-basic-info__view-jobs-button" data-cta="viewOpenJobsForCompany" data-js="company-search-view-jobs-button-reg" href="https://[internal url not really important for the question]">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    <div class="company-basic-info__description">
        <div class="company-basic-info__description-text" data-attr="expandable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, inani labores eligendi ex cum, labitur equidem recteque eam eu. Ignota semper mentitum ad vim, aperiam volumus iracundia ne mea, eu eros movet mel. Sed ea natum elaboraret. Mel modus aliquid reformidans ei, postea putent splendide an eum.
       Sanctus indoctum mea id, feugiat placerat mei ea. An scripta epicurei theophrastus has, vis eu illud principes moderatius. Facer velit sed ei, atqui dicta ornatus ea vix, nec soluta populo ei. Quis laudem nec cu, sed viderer theophrastus id.
       </div>
        <div class="company-basic-info__description-expander" data-attr="expander" style="display: block;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: To be clear: None of these click methods works, and the screenshot does not show the modal? Does `casper.exists('[data-js="company-search-view-jobs-button-reg"]')` return true? Note that Casper is (probably) not using the same DOM selector machinery as jQuery, so jQuery giving you the right element doesn't guarantee Casper can find it with the same selector.

Comment: thanks for the comments. accidentally submitted.. editing..
<br/>
casper.exists('[data-js="company-search-view-jobs-button-reg"]') returns true.
<br/>
adding those event listeners, i see "error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.hideOnClickAway.bind(this)')", which looks promising.   i don't see an error like that in the chrome console, and i'm not sure why that's happening when the page loads.

Comment: On further investigation, I think that error is key.  It looks like that error is preventing the click handlers from working. If I change the button to just an <a> tag, then the click works.  I have no idea why that error happens in Casper but not chrome, though.

Comment: Did you try running the code from `casper.evaluate` in a browser console on your page, does it works then?
Programmatic click may work differently from a 'real-life' mouse click since in browser you do mousedown->mouseup->click with an correct event properties (event position can matter), instead of simple 'click' triggered by test. In case  you have a tricky event handler this can make a difference

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was this line

```
casper.options.remoteScripts.push 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'
```

The casperjs Jquery injection overwrited the addEventListeners so they were not working. Remove that line and test if it works. Modify your code to use plain javascript instead of Jquery lib.