# Casperjs click() doesn't trigger click event correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax, click, casperjs, image-loading

I'm using CasperJS for web scraping, but I encountered some problems on scraping the page I describe below.

The html of the page looks like this:

```
<img id="trigger">
<img id="cur_img_xxx" class="show">
<img id="cur_img_yyy" class="cache">
```

All `<img>` elements share the same dimensions, and `"#trigger"` is on the topmost layer. When an image has `.show` class, it will display on the page; when it's `.cache` class, it will get downloaded but hide. In this way, when user click on the image, which is actually the trigger, next image will show and a new image will be downloaded via AJAX. The resulted html becomes:

```
<img id="trigger">
<img id="cur_img_xxx" class="cache">
<img id="cur_img_yyy" class="show">
<img id="cur_img_zzz" class="cache">
```

I guess it's a good strategy to increase the UX, and good for avoiding web scraping, but I still want to scrape :P

I tried `$("#trigger").click()` in the web console, and the images get navigated and downloaded corrected. However, when I tried to simulate this process using CasperJS, neither the navigation nor the image downloading worked. Please refer to the code:

```
var casper = require ("casper").create({
  clientScripts:  [
    'include/jquery.js'
  ],
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages:  false, // this won't affect since this will only forbid
    loadPlugins: false  // inline imgs from loading, but all imgs in this
  },                    // page are loaded dynamically
  verbose: true
});

casper.start("http://www.example.com/1234.html");

casper.then(function () {
  console.log("Connected! Current Url = " + this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.then(function () {
  // findInitialImgs will find imgs that have already been loaded 
  imgs = this.evaluate(findInitialImgs);

  this.waitForSelector("#image_trigger").thenClick("#image_trigger");

  var next = this.evaluate(function () {
    return $("img[id^='cur_img_']").last().attr("href");
  });

  console.log(next);
});

casper.run(function () {
  this.echo('End').exit();
});
```

By right, after `"#trigger"` is clicked, the last entry would be different, i.e. from `<img id="cur_img_yyy">` becomes `<img id="cur_img_zzz">`. However, `next` still held `<img id="cur_img_yyy">`. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616350/casperjs-click-not-firing-click-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be `JQuery`'s problem. After I deleted `JQuery` injection, and changed `$("img[id^='cur_img_']").last().attr("href")` to

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img[id^='cur_img_']");
return imgs[imgs.length - 1].getAttribute("href");
```

Everything works fine.

Then I found this answer very powerful: [CasperJS click event having AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098483/casperjs-click-event-having-ajax-call?rq=1)

So confirmed that the original scripts will be broken when you inject `JQuery` to pages that use `$` as `JQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

How do you validate that nothing happens? All `wait*()` and `then*()` functions are asynchronous step functions, but `evaluate` is not, so it is executed before the other two. You need to wrap the last `evaluate` call in a `then` block to make sure the step that contains it is executed after clicking.

Since image loading is probably executed asynchronously, you would need to wrap the last `evaluate` call in a `wait` block with a short wait time:

```
casper.then(function () {
  // findInitialImgs will find imgs that have already been loaded 
  imgs = this.evaluate(findInitialImgs);

  this.waitForSelector("#image_trigger")
    .thenClick("#image_trigger")
    .wait(1000, function(){
      var next = this.evaluate(function () {
        return $("img[id^='cur_img_']").last()[0].id;
      });
      console.log(next);
    });
});
```

Note that you can't pass DOM nodes out of the page context (`evaluate()`), so you need to use some kind of representation of that. Here I used the id of the last element.

For [reference](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) (`casper.evaluate()` is only a wrapper around PhantomJS' `page.evaluate()`):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

Comment: I've edited the question above to show how I validated nothing happened. I will take your advice to have a try :)

Comment: I've extended my answer with an example and a fix for a problem that I haven't noticed before.

Comment: oh it's my fault that didn't express clearly. In the code should be `$("img[id^='cur_img_']").last().attr("href")`. Sorry about this :`(